# HTML5 Attribute Manipulation: Vanilla JS vs. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, attributes

How come changing elements' attribute values in vanilla JS and jQuery sometimes don't work similarly? One scenario is the experiment I created, where whenever the "Show password" button is being clicked, the password field's `type` attribute value is supposed to change into `text` when it is `password`, and vice versa. It worked successfully in vanilla JS but not in jQuery. In jQuery, the attribute value changes to `text`, but when I want to change it back to `password`, it won't work. Why does such issue occur?

Vanilla JS

```
document.querySelector('.show-password').onclick = function() {
    if(document.querySelector('#password').type == 'password') {
        document.querySelector('#password').type = 'text';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#password').type = 'password';
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.show-password').click(function() {
    if($('#password').attr('type', 'password')) {
        $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
    } else {
        $('#password').attr('type', 'password');
    }
});
```

Comment: It should be `if($('#password').attr('type') == 'password')`. [Rubberduck-debug](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. There’s no reason 7 lines of code should fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `if($('#password').attr('type', 'password'))` is not asking if the type attribute is 'password'. It is setting type=password and [returning a jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to the if statement.

When .attr() is used with only [one parameter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1), it gets that attribute from the selected element, so yo can do it using `$("#password").attr("type") == "password"`.